# Paypal "Invalid Response"

Tags: php, paypal, woocommerce

Im having problems with paypal standard. All of my orders are going into pending in woocommerce, but they are completed from paypal. It was working fine up until yesterday. Have checked paypal notification and nothing seems to be the problem with them posting IPN. Have even called paypal and they suggested it must be a problem with woocommerce.

All I get is a " Received invalid response from PayPal" message. Nothing else.

Very grateful for any help.

Here is the log:

```
08-03-2014 @ 09:52:33 - Generating payment form for order #3264. Notify URL: http://www.example.com/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/
08-03-2014 @ 09:52:58 - Checking IPN response is valid via https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr...
08-03-2014 @ 09:52:58 - IPN Request: Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [cmd] => _notify-validate
            [mc_gross] => 0.01
            [invoice] => WC-3264
            [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
            [item_number1] => 
            [payer_id] => 75CDQE99MV6HU
            [tax] => 0.00
            [payment_date] => 02:52:47 Aug 03, 2014 PDT
            [payment_status] => Completed
            [charset] => windows-1252
            [mc_shipping] => 0.00
            [mc_handling] => 0.00
            [first_name] => blah
            [mc_fee] => 0.01
            [notify_version] => 3.8
            [custom] => a:2:{i:0;i:3264;i:1;s:22:"wc_order_53de066107428";}
            [payer_status] => verified
            [business] => blahblahblah@hotmail.com
            [num_cart_items] => 1
            [mc_handling1] => 0.00
            [verify_sign] => A1K1xiWGhsY-FKnWkd4yY7uiudGNAOARq2ctsv1RwgUf2oeUWPvl8xHQ
            [payer_email] => blahblahblah@hotmail.com
            [mc_shipping1] => 0.00
            [tax1] => 0.00
            [txn_id] => 0SY73148U75396444
            [payment_type] => instant
            [last_name] => blahblah
            [item_name1] => Test
            [receiver_email] => blahblahblah@hotmail.com
            [payment_fee] => 
            [quantity1] => 1
            [receiver_id] => 63MGUUP668W7Y
            [txn_type] => cart
            [mc_gross_1] => 0.01
            [mc_currency] => GBP
            [residence_country] => GB
            [transaction_subject] => a:2:{i:0;i:3264;i:1;s:22:"wc_order_53de066107428";}
            [payment_gross] => 
            [ipn_track_id] => 9ac6a002221f7
        )

    [sslverify] => 
    [timeout] => 60
    [httpversion] => 1.1
    [compress] => 
    [decompress] => 
    [user-agent] => WooCommerce/2.1.12
)

08-03-2014 @ 09:52:58 - IPN Response: Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [server] => Apache
            [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
            [strict-transport-security] => Array
                (
                    [0] => max-age=14400
                    [1] => max-age=14400
                )

            [content-type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [dc] => slc-a-origin-www-2.paypal.com
            [date] => Sun, 03 Aug 2014 09:52:58 GMT
            [transfer-encoding] => chunked
            [connection] => Array
                (
                    [0] => close
                    [1] => Transfer-Encoding
                )

            [set-cookie] => Array
                (
                    [0] => cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=YvFeUiPBnGc9JrBsDcwjbDJQBiP7vJQt0UKZ9_Bzlhtmh2d7UWs2aYg-ENdINNTeQOU_tVg_MLrSb7aedZf4esd8jHXCDRA06es2hAkvXFzT2ImoQc5cEwK6-9bOvt8mxoR4Q1wcqh1q7-Xka84IkDmsLD34Y9kVuh13e6fatgxirOzN4LxgTbJzxGBJBuEJnRcHJ18ofyIq_u5plMzhy6V_Qd7A-QT5gJiEr5ZTgJ5cAAtoX_44lYgXKvSFWIKdag7NORd_AkLYiiZUjnf0A-Xs909CeHcisY0rbeiD_f1iEueyX8-8qHNWCqZi3l2ZCzuUpQ_or1TpGt83eIArYtLtov2y8AdLkHKWd890yalOsG30jwCJseRE3UFxoQiUvqrwSd3bGq35PYHB3XN42ZXdXmHE0RstOuRnPdQQLC3J413su_zQfeiSzfe; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
                    [1] => cookie_check=yes; expires=Wed, 31-Jul-2024 09:52:58 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
                    [2] => navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
                    [3] => navlns=0.0; expires=Tue, 02-Aug-2016 09:52:58 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
                    [4] => Apache=10.73.8.134.1407059578400130; path=/; expires=Tue, 26-Jul-44 09:52:58 GMT
                    [5] => X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE5.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dslingshot%26TIME%3D2047270483; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
                    [6] => X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
                    [7] => Apache=10.73.8.67.1407059578390277; path=/; expires=Tue, 26-Jul-44 09:52:58 GMT
                    [8] => AKDC=slc-a-origin-www-2.paypal.com; expires=Sun, 03-Aug-2014 10:22:58 GMT; path=/; secure
                )

        )

    [body] => 00000008
VERIFIED
00000000


    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG
                    [value] => YvFeUiPBnGc9JrBsDcwjbDJQBiP7vJQt0UKZ9_Bzlhtmh2d7UWs2aYg-ENdINNTeQOU_tVg_MLrSb7aedZf4esd8jHXCDRA06es2hAkvXFzT2ImoQc5cEwK6-9bOvt8mxoR4Q1wcqh1q7-Xka84IkDmsLD34Y9kVuh13e6fatgxirOzN4LxgTbJzxGBJBuEJnRcHJ18ofyIq_u5plMzhy6V_Qd7A-QT5gJiEr5ZTgJ5cAAtoX_44lYgXKvSFWIKdag7NORd_AkLYiiZUjnf0A-Xs909CeHcisY0rbeiD_f1iEueyX8-8qHNWCqZi3l2ZCzuUpQ_or1TpGt83eIArYtLtov2y8AdLkHKWd890yalOsG30jwCJseRE3UFxoQiUvqrwSd3bGq35PYHB3XN42ZXdXmHE0RstOuRnPdQQLC3J413su_zQfeiSzfe
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => .paypal.com
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

            [1] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => cookie_check
                    [value] => yes
                    [expires] => 1722419578
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => .paypal.com
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

            [2] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => navcmd
                    [value] => _notify-validate
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => .paypal.com
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

            [3] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => navlns
                    [value] => 0.0
                    [expires] => 1470131578
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => .paypal.com
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

            [4] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => Apache
                    [value] => 10.73.8.134.1407059578400130
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => www.paypal.com
                )

            [5] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => X-PP-SILOVER
                    [value] => name=LIVE5.WEB.1&silo_version=880&app=slingshot&TIME=2047270483
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => .paypal.com
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

            [6] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => X-PP-SILOVER
                    [value] => 
                    [expires] => 1
                    [path] => /cgi-bin/
                    [domain] => www.paypal.com
                )

            [7] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => Apache
                    [value] => 10.73.8.67.1407059578390277
                    [expires] => 
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => www.paypal.com
                )

            [8] => WP_Http_Cookie Object
                (
                    [name] => AKDC
                    [value] => slc-a-origin-www-2.paypal.com
                    [expires] => 1407061378
                    [path] => /
                    [domain] => www.paypal.com
                    [secure] => 
                )

        )

    [filename] => 
)

08-03-2014 @ 09:52:58 - Received invalid response from PayPal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[body] => INVALID
```

**PayPal is returning Invalid, but its still talking to them. Maybe before this:**

```
if ( 'yes' == $this->debug ) $this->log->add( 'paypal', 'IPN Response: ' . print_r( $response, true ) );
```

**Replaced this with:**

```
if ( 'yes' == $this->debug ) $this->log->add( 'paypal', 'IPN Request: ' . print_r( $params, true ) );
```

Then checked the log - it told the request its making to paypal.